# How to tell which Tab is currently open? Wet-Boew plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using the tabbed interface from the Wet-boews Toolkit ([http://wet-boew.github.io/v4.0-ci/docs/ref/tabs/tabs-en.htm](https://wet-boew.github.io/v4.0-ci/demos/tabs/tabs-en.html)l)

After to page has loaded, how can I determine which Tab is open.

I have tried the below but strangely they all return true

```
     <div class="wb-tabs">  
       <div class="tabpanels">      
          <details id="details-panel-panel1">
                <summary>Example 1</summary> 
                <p>                 ...             </p>        
         </details> 
        <details id="details-panel-panel2"> 
              <summary>Example 2</summary> 
               <p>              ...             </p>        
     </details>        </div>  </div>


var panel1 = ($("details-panel-panel1").attr("open")) ? true : false;
var panel2 = ($("details-panel-panel2").attr("open")) ? true : false;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two tips:

- To get an element by `id` you need to add the `#` character before the id `$('#details-panel-panel1')`
- `$("#details-panel-panel1").attr("open")` will get you the value of the attribute `open`, it won't tell you if exist (won't be a boolean).

Said that, I couldn't find anything in the documentation, but I was looking at the generated code, and actually you cannot tell if the tab is open by looking at the `open` attribute. But I notice two things:

- The attribute `aria-expanded` is true on the open tab, and false on the rest.
- The open tab has the class `in`, the others have `out`.

You can go either way:

```
$('#details-panel10').attr('aria-expanded') === "true"
```

or

```
$('#details-panel10').hasClass('in') === true
```